# Android Studio и Eclipse не видят аппараты

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

Здравствуйте.
Я недавно начал изучать разработку под Андроид. Установил обе среды, скачал пакеты, эмулятор работает. Но вот подключить какой-нибудь аппарат к компьютеру (через USB для тестирования) не получается. Пробовал подключать Meizu MX4 Pro, планшет Nexus 7 и Samsung Galaxy s3/s4. Ни один аппарат не обнаружен. Ни в Эклипсе, ни в Студии.

Спасибо, все заработало! Итак, проблема была в оболочке от Meizu. Пункт "отладка по USB" находится в настройках сканера пальца. Случайно нашел, даже не предполагал, что это может быть там.

Comment: Режим отладки включили на девайсе в настройках разработчика?

Comment: Какую ОС вы используете?

Comment: ОС Windows 7 Ultimate.

Comment: Оформите свое решение проблемы ответом и отметьте его верным

Answer (score 1):

Возможны варианты:

1. Не те дрова для подключения девайса по юсб (попробуйте поставить те, что лежат в

> \sdk\extras\google\usb_driver

2. Плохой кабель. У меня был случай, когда один кабель работал с одним девйсом и не работал с другим. Попробуйте заменить кабель.
3. Как заметил @anber, надо включить режим отладки по юсб в настройках для разработчиков на девайсе.
4. Все три предыдущих пункта вместе.

Answer (score 1):

Вы выставляли в андроиде отпладку по *usb*?

Она выставляется в `настройки->для разработчиков->отладка по usb`.

Также требуются рабочие *adb-драйвера* (в диспетчере задач ваше устройство должно правильно определяться).

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало! Итак, проблема была в оболочке от Meizu. Пункт "отладка по USB" находится в настройках сканера пальца. Случайно нашел, даже не предполагал, что это может быть там.

Answer (score 1):

Диспетчер устройст определяет ваши устройства? И как, там есть android adb device или чтото подобное?
Ваши телефоны включили отладку по usb?
Скачивали просто adb и делали
Adb devices?

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь. Знакомая студентка показала мне на примере своего LG G3 как соединяться по кабелю с Андроид Студио. У нее все работало отлично, я сам видел. Проблема в моем аппарате. У Meizu стоит своя оболочка повер Андроид, оттуда и все проблемы. Я не могу найти в настройках пункт отладка по USB. Нашел пару статей по этому аппарату, буду разбираться... Если кто имел дело именно с Meizu, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Установите pdaNet+ на РС, затем, следуя инструкциям этой программы,
установите pdaNet на андроид-устройство.
Возможно, потребуется в этой проге (на андроид-девайсе) выбрать опцию Activate USB Tether. Попадете на страницу для разработчиков, где можно включить режим юсб-отладки. Не во всех устройствах эта опция и так присутствует в настройках.
Кроме того, в настройках юсб-подключения (после подключения девайса к компу) может по умолчанию выбираться режим "только зарядка". Надо изменить на "Медиа-устройство".

Answer (score 0):

1. Проблема все же не зависит от IDE, тут проблема в adb.
2. Попробуйте поставить UADB: https://github.com/koush/UniversalAdbDriver.
3. Если не помогло, загляните в диспетчер устройств, найдите там подключенный девайс и вручную укажите ему драйвер из uadb.

Answer (score 0):

У меня на Huawei Honor 3c lite была та же проблема. Проблема решилась после отключения автозапуска на ПК программы HiSuite - менеджер синхронизации файлов и фоток телефонов Huawei с Windows PC. Он стартовал и не давал Android Studio подключаться к телефону. Драйвера ADB устанавливались вместе с HiSuite, но его работа в фоне мешала Android Studio, видимо они одновременно к телефону обращались.

Чтобы включить "Режим разработчика", где находится "отладка по USB" - надо войти в меню "Настройка" - "О телефоне" - 10 раз нажать на надпись "номер сборки".

Comment: Даже в вопросе вроде уже есть решение. Почему вы считаете, что ваш ответ будет полезен?